# Change a boolean value after resize

Tags: css, reactjs

I am currently facing an issue with my navigation bar,
I added a ReorderIcon button that toggles a boolean to true or false when I click on it and it displays my Contact Us, About and Sponsor Us page when the screen is small, but the issue I am facing is a small bug.

When I click on the button so the boolean flag goes to true, and the i enlarge my window, the boolean does not go back to false, and I was wondering how I could do that.

Here is the issue in picture:

[image: Before click]
[image: After Click]
[image: Bug Happening]

Here is my React code:

```js
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import "../styles/NavBar.css";
import Logo from "../assets/logo.png";
import ReorderIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Reorder';
export default function NavBar(){
    const [openLinks, setOpenLinks] = useState(false);

    const toggleNavbar = () => {
        setOpenLinks(!openLinks);
    };
    return (
        <div className="navbar">
            <div className="leftSide" id={openLinks? "open" : "close"}>
                <Link to="/">
                <img src={Logo}  alt=''/>
                </Link>
                <div className="hiddenLinks">
                    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                    <Link to="/sponsor">Parrainez Nous</Link>
                    <Link to="/about">À propos</Link>
                    <Link to="/contact"><div className='contact'>Contact</div></Link>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="rightSide">
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                <Link to="/sponsor">Parrainez Nous</Link>
                <Link to="/about">À propos</Link>
                <Link to="/contact"><div className='contact'>Contact</div></Link>
                <button onClick={toggleNavbar}>
                    <ReorderIcon />
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Here is my CSS:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins');
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #121619;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.navbar .leftSide {
    flex: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.navbar .rightSide .contact{
    background-color: #1762A7;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;

}


.navbar .leftSide img {
    width: 100px;
}

.navbar .rightSide {
    flex: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.navbar a {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 20px;
}

.navbar .rightSide button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar .rightSide svg {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.navbar #open {
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.navbar #open img {
    display: none;
}

.navbar #close img {
    display: inherit;
}

.navbar #open .hiddenLinks {
    display: inherit;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

.navbar #close .hiddenLinks {
    display: none;
}

.navbar #open a {
    width: 70px;
    margin: 5px;
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .navbar .rightSide a {
        width: 70px;
    }
    .navbar .leftSide {
        padding-left: 50px;
    }
    .navbar .contact{
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 638px) {
    .navbar .rightSide a {
        display: none;
    }

    .navbar .rightSide {
        justify-content: flex-end;
        padding-right: 50px;
    }

    .navbar .rightSide button {
        display: inherit;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 638px) {
    .navbar .rightSide button {
        display: none;
    }

    .hiddenLinks {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly here but let's see. I think you can't really make a CSS change your variable value but you can setup your own React hook that watches for the window resizing event.

```
import { useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export const useResWidth = (width: number) => {
  
  const [resizing, setResizing] = useState(false);
  const [sizeX, setSizeX] = useState(window.innerWidth);

  useEffect(() => {
    const onResize = () => {
      setSizeX(window.innerWidth);
      setResizing(window.innerWidth > sizeX);
    };
    
    window.addEventListener('resize', onResize);
    sizeX > width  ? setResizing(true) : setResizing(false);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', onResize);
  }, [sizeX]);

  return resizing;

};
```

You can import this hook into your component and then use it as:

```
const isOverWidth1000 = useResWidth(1000); // sets the isOverWidth1000 as true if width exceeds 1000, false otherwise
```

or use it with ternary and set myVariable as a string depending on outcome:

```
const myVariable = useResWidth(1024) ? 'Width is over 1024!' : 'Below 1024';
```

You can customize the custom hook to your liking as well. You can set it up in a way it returns the current width etc.

Sorry if this doesn't explain your question, as I said I wasn't 100% sure what you were looking for.

EDIT: I used my typescript code, edit it if you want to use it without types.
EDIT2: For clarity: You can definitely use the logic inside of your component but I always prefer to implement it outside of the component for future re-usability.

Comment: `sizeX > width  ? setResizing(true) : setResizing(false)` -> this can be `setResizing(sizeX > width)`.

Comment: I think this was it, i will add this so when i change the size of my window it simulates that the button is clicked.Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Ravinala hopefully it will work for you but also read what moonwave99 commented above as they are are spot on with the suggestion. Will make your code even cleaner :)